# Вернуть номер виджета

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

К примеру, в цикле я создаю три виджета `Entry`:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

for i in range(3):
    e = Entry(root).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Как забиндить комманду `(e.bind('<Return>',command))` на возврат номера виджета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ получить номер виджета - явно добавить ему нужное поле:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def handler(event):
    messagebox.showinfo('', str(event.widget.number))

root = Tk()

for i in range(3):
    e = Entry(root)
    e.pack()
    e.number = i
    e.bind('<Return>', handler)

root.mainloop()
```

Но таким способом добавлять поля чужому классу не очень хорошо, т.к. выбранное имя может пересечься с имеющимся полем, что может сломать логику работы объекта.

Другой вариант - сделать "переходную" лямбда-функцию, которая будет "помнить" номер виджета, к которому она привязана:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def handler(event, number):
    messagebox.showinfo('', str(number))

root = Tk()

for i in range(3):
    e = Entry(root)
    e.pack()
    e.bind('<Return>', lambda event, i=i: handler(event, i))

root.mainloop()
```

Еще один способ: можно воспользоваться тем, что объекты tkinter хэшируемы, поэтому их можно использовать как ключи в словаре, значениями в котором будут номера виджетов:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

to_index = dict()

def handler(event):
    messagebox.showinfo('', str(to_index[event.widget]))

root = Tk()

for i in range(3):
    e = Entry(root)
    e.pack()
    e.bind('<Return>', handler)
    to_index[e] = i

root.mainloop()
```